# how to capture group within capture group?

Tags: regex, pcre

for example, string:

```
bla bla bla (bla oops bla
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla) bla oops
bla bla bla 
oops bla (bla bla oops
bla)
```

how i can get 'oops' between brackets?
first, i get text between brackets:

```
(?<=\()([\w\W]*?)(?=\))
```

can i in the same regex capture group within capture group (find 'oops' within capture group)?

Comment: If you have PHP, `\([^()]*\Koops(?=[^()]*\))`. In .NET, `(?<=\([^()]*)oops(?=[^()]*\))`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342679/match-specific-word-between-brackets, too

Comment: Eventually, a lot depends on what you need to get in the end (usually, extract or replace).

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much for php-regex!!!!!!!!! Now I understand how `\K` works.

Comment: and also i didn't know that quantifiers work whithin lookahead/lookbehind in some languages (e.g. .NET). Thank you for that information.

Comment: i've one more question. can i get multiple "oops" whithin brackets (on PHP, i.e without quantifiers whithin lookahead/lookbehind)? if string:bla bla bla (bla oops bla bla oops bla bla bla bla bla) bla oops bla bla bla oops bla (bla bla oops bla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\()[^()]*?\Koops
```

Or, if you must check for the closing parentheses, add a lookahead at the end:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\()[^()]*?\Koops(?=[^()]*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QZ9H1g/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\()` - `(` or end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`)
- `[^()]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\K` - [match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `oops` - the word you need (wrap with `\b` if you need a whole word match)
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that requires 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` up to the first `)` to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: thank you very much. You made me study regular espressions in more detail. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=\()([\w\W]*?(oops)[\w\W]*?)(?=\))
```

Basically it injects a `Group` looking for `'oops'` then it doubles the '`[\w\W]*?`' matching both before and after the captured Group.

Now `'oops'` will be in `Group 2`.